# Royal TS - Unable to Save RTSZ File

Tags: windows, permissions, lock

I added a resource to Royal TS and tried to save the rtsz document, but it popped up with an error complaining about a lock file that supposedly doesn't exist.

As it's saving, it shows this:[image: Merging, please wait...]
[image: Failed to Save Document]

Title: Failed to Save Document
Content: Error saving document *'lab'* to the file '`C:\Users\[REDACTED]\Documents\Homelab.rtsz`'. Could not find file '`C:\Users\[REDACTED]\Documents\Homelab.lock`'

Sure enough, I don't see the .lock file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I was writing the question, I had a realization... I had been ignoring a popup from Windows Security on the side of my screen. This must have been the first time I tried saving a Royal TS document since enabling Ransomware Protection (Windows Security > Virus & threat protection > Ransomware protection > Controlled folder access). I went through the block history and found the most recent history entry was for royalTS.exe to `%userprofile%\Documents\`. I selected the actions context button and then chose "allow on this device". After doing this, I tried saving once more and it worked perfectly.

[image: Protected folder access blocked]

It turns out that Royal TS probably tried checking or creating the .lock file, was blocked by Microsoft Ransomware Protection and errored out.